# How does the bounty auto-award work?

Tags: support, bounty

This just happened [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20723/12102). What are the precise rules with which the auto-awarding algorithm operates?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [bounty page](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) in the help centre:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period
>   ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top
>   voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of
>   at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation
>   will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be
>   lost forever.

The answer to your question was posted after you started the bounty and has a score of 5, therefore qualifying for the algorithm giving it 50 reputation from your 100 rep bounty.